# Invoking SQL Agent Jobs

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I am trying to Invoke a SQL agent job from my C# Application.

I want to be able to.

- On the Press of a button be able to Execute the Job.

But i also want to have some sort of message for when the job is finished running or fails.

The Below Code sampe from another Answer will not work for me as i need access to the local MSDB database.

```
private Dictionary<int, string> ExecutionStatusDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
{0, "Not idle or suspended"},
{1, "Executing"},
{2, "Waiting for thread"},
{3, "Between retries"},
{4, "Idle"},
{5, "Suspended"},
{7, "Performing completion actions"}
};

public string GetStatus()
{
SqlConnection msdbConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GACDTL01CR585M;Initial       Catalog=msdb;Integrated Security=SSPI");
System.Text.StringBuilder resultBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

try
{
    msdbConnection.Open();

    SqlCommand jobStatusCommand = msdbConnection.CreateCommand();

    jobStatusCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    jobStatusCommand.CommandText = "sp_help_job";

    SqlParameter jobName = jobStatusCommand.Parameters.Add("@job_name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    jobName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    jobName.Value = "LoadRegions";

    SqlParameter jobAspect = jobStatusCommand.Parameters.Add("@job_aspect", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    jobAspect.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    jobAspect.Value = "JOB";

    SqlDataReader jobStatusReader = jobStatusCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (jobStatusReader.Read())
    {
        resultBuilder.Append(string.Format("{0} {1}",
            jobStatusReader["name"].ToString(),
            ExecutionStatusDictionary[(int)jobStatusReader["current_execution_status"]]
        ));
    }
    jobStatusReader.Close();
}
finally
{
    msdbConnection.Close();
}

return resultBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ADO.NET is not appropriate for what you want to do.
You should be using the [SQL Server Management Objects API (`SMO`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which is preferred when doing administrative tasks this way.

More exactly, you should have a look at SMO's [`Job.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms202348%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) method. There's a sample in the article on how to use it. 
The `Job` class provides some events (such as `SuccessAction`) to notify you when the job is finished executing.